# Alphabetize Apps Screen (not Home, maybe App Drawer?)

Tags: archos-gen8, app-drawer

I have an Archos 32 with the 2.2.1 (or Archos 2.1.18) version of Android installed. When I press the onscreen button to show all installed apps, I noticed that some downloaded apps are out of alphabetical order. There seems to be no option to alphabetize them. Does anyone know an app or other solution that can correct this?

Note: Is this called the app drawer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an Archos, but when I view all apps on my phone I can press the Menu button and select a view type from in there (including alphabetical).  Do you have anything similar?

You could also try another launcher, such as ADW.

And yes, it's often called the app drawer :)

Comment: No view type option. Would an alternate launcher automatically replace the stock one once installed?

Comment: @Richard I haven't done this myself, but I believe you can have two launchers side-by-side.  One will be set as the default, and if you want to switch back you can either uninstall the new one or go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`, find the new launcher, and clear the defaults.

Comment: Or don't press the check mark for USE AS DEFAULT and with an additional click choose which app you want to use each time the HOME button is used.

Comment: the gen 8s basically run very vanilla android so he won't have that option, he'll need an alternative launcher.